# Rstudio lmtest Error in model.frame.default

Tags: r, regression

I have excel data for my work and my datas are double. Can't do OLS test in R. What i need to do?

```
Error:
model <- lm(CO2~EnergyD+Export , data = econ324)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = CO2 ~ EnergyD + Export, data = econ324,  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'CO2'
```

Did granger, unit root and cointegration tests w same data serie. Tried to delete NA values, even there is no NA section in data. I can't fix that.

I want to do OLS test

Comment: From the error message, the dependent variable is in a list format, when it needs to be a vector. It's difficult to help further without seeing the data. Providing the output of `dput(econ324)` as part of your question to make the issue reproducible would help.